# How to apply a TimeSpan value to a DateTimeOffset?

Tags: c#, api, timespan, datetimeoffset

How to apply a `TimeSpan` value to a `DateTimeOffset`?

How can I do this?

I have one `DateTimeOffset` like 29/03/2020 13:20:40 and I need to apply a `TimeSpan` with the value -03:00:00.

And in result I need to get 29/03/2020 10:20:40

Comment: [`Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.add?view=netcore-3.1) method

Comment: Just use the + operator, var newdate = date + time;

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below code

```
DateTimeOffset value = offset.AddHours(-3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like:

```
DateTimeOffset past = yourTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromHours(3));
```